# Exclude directory from rewrite rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Below is my .htaccess file. I am trying to exclude the rewrite rules being applied to the /admin/ folder, however after spending an hour researching and trying various codes I have reached a wall.

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

# Exclude admin directory    
RewriteRule ^(admin|admin)($|/) - [L]

RewriteRule ^privacy$ pages/privacy.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.+)$ products.php?q=$3&rewrite=1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/$ search.php?q=bw:&categoryFilter=$1&genreFilter=$2%{QUERY_STRING} [L,B]

RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ pages/format.php?format=$1 [NC,L}   

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.) 
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
```

The above code brings an internal 500 error and if I remove it will redirect me to the rewrite rule for the format. I was reading that The exclusion rewrite rule needs to be placed before the rule I want to overwrite. I don't understand why it's not working and what I have missed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try and write your rule this way.

```
# Exclude admin directory    
RewriteRule ^admin/?$ - [L]
```

Comment: What do you mean it `doesnt` work? It still allows it or you get an error?

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your .htaccess.

Have your .htaccess like this:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Exclude admin directory    
RewriteRule ^admin($|/) - [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.) 
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^privacy$ pages/privacy.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)/(.+)$ products.php?q=$3&rewrite=1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/$ search.php?q=bw:&categoryFilter=$1&genreFilter=$2 [L,B,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ pages/format.php?format=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: There was a typo, it is fixed. Try again.